# Window Resize Perform action with exactly the size

Tags: javascript, url

with url parameters:

index.php?variante=mobile

index.php?variante=desktop

I can switch between views.

Now I want to change automatically with window.resize() views, as in Responsive Theme. The best so inconspicuously as possible.

The website must be show exactly at 960px desktop version, and at 959px show the mobile version.

My script using Ajax request works, but there are too many Ajax requests.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();

  function reloadPage() {
    if (windowWidth != $(window).width()) {
      location.reload();
    }
  }

  function setDesktop() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'www.mywebsite.com/index.php?variante=desktop',
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {}
    })
  }

  function setMobile() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'www.mywebsite.com/index.php?variante=mobile',
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {}
    })
  }

  function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize <= 959) {
      setMobile();
      reloadPage();
    } else if (windowsize >= 960) {
      setDesktop();
      reloadPage();
    }
  }
  checkWidth();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    checkWidth();
  });
});
```

Do you tip for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check if the `AJAX call` has already launched with a `boolean` (mobileSet) like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $window = $(window);
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  var mobileSet = false;


  function reloadPage() {
    if (windowWidth != $(window).width()) {
      location.reload();
    }
  }

  function setDesktop() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'www.mywebsite.com/index.php?variante=desktop',
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {}
    })
  }

  function setMobile() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'www.mywebsite.com/index.php?variante=mobile',
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {}
    })
  }

  function checkWidth() {
    var windowsize = $window.width();
    if (windowsize <= 959 && mobileSet == false) {
      setMobile();
      mobileSet = true;
      reloadPage();
    } else if (windowsize >= 960 && mobileSet == true) {
      setDesktop();
      mobileSet = false;
      reloadPage();
    }
  }
  checkWidth();
  $(window).resize(function() {
    checkWidth();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank You! It only works with Chrome, not Firefox. It appears wrong version. From 960px Mobile version, and under 960px desktop. Only with manual refresh the page, the correct version is displayed.

Comment: that can not function because each time the page is reloaded, the variable mobileSet is set to false. :-)

Comment: True, you should set the boolean on pageload by detecting the window width after you have declared the global variables windowWidth and $window:

if (windowWidth >= 960) { setMobile = true } else { false }

Comment: No need. I can query directly from the template, your approach has helped me a lot.

Comment: ´if (window width> = 960) {setMobile = true} else {false}´

That can not work well, because I check the variable here:
´
if (windowsize <= 959 && mobileSet == false)

Comment: That function is only called when you are resizing and on documen tready so you need to call the checkWidth function in the if else statement I provided with the defining of setMobile Boolean to get it working right